# Find objects which contains subjects with given parameter

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to figure out NSPredicate which will find all objects which contains subjects with given parameter.

I have this objects:

```
@interface User : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableOrderedSet * items;

@end
```

and:

```
@interface Item : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * itemId;

@end
```

I have array of users and I want to find all users which contain item with itemId == 1.

Have no more clues how to get it

Comment: Please elaborate. These are not subclasses of `NSManagedObject`. How did you come up with these objects and what exactly is not working?

Comment: User objects contain multiple items??

Comment: Sorry I have just made it, orginaly they are subclasses of NSManaged Object

Comment: Yes user contains multiple items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSNumber *theItemId = @1; // The id that you are looking for
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY items.itemId == %@", theItemId];
```

should do it. You can use this predicate in a *fetch request* to fetch all matching users,
or with `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` to filter an *array* of users.